# flutter firestore data read

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
getData() async {
    var a = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('1_email', isEqualTo:currentUser.currentUser!.email).snapshots();
    print(a);
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
   getData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Console :

> flutter: Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'

```
getData() async {
    var a = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('1_email', isEqualTo:currentUser.currentUser!.email).get();
    print(a);
  }
@override
  void initState() {
   getData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Console :

> flutter: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'

The code above is, if the user's email logged in to the Firebase matches the email contained in the Firestore database, please pull the data

However, if you treat it as `print(a['1_email])`
the following error appears (pictured attached)

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'. (Documentation)  Try defining the operator '[]'.

[image: Error]

How can I get the data below?

[image: Firestore]

Comment: Wrap it inside parentheses like
                                                                                                        
getData() async {
    var a = (await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')).where('1_email', isEqualTo:currentUser.currentUser!.email).get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot)
    => ???);
    print(a['1_email']);
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing a query, which can have multiple results. Your code doesn't handle the fact that there may be multiple results.

To handle this correctly with a one-time read operation, would be:

```
getData() async {
  var querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('1_email', isEqualTo:currentUser.currentUser!.email).get();
  for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
    print(docSnapshot.get("1_email"));
  }
}
```

The code change is pretty much copy/paste from the Firebase documentation section on [executing a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).

Comment: Thank you. We've solved the problem of reading the data in this way
However, when I try to use getData() inside the container, I get the following error: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'